# onchange in custom select dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a custom select dropdown refering the following tutorial.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

But the issue is `onchange` is not working for the select dropdown.

```
<div class="custom-select-dropdown">
    <select id="agro-time-period" onchange="agroTimePeriod()" class="custom-input">
       <option disabled selected hidden value="">Ex: Year 2020</option>
           {% for time in agro_time_periods %}
              <option value="{{time.code}},{{time.name}}">{{time.name}}</option>
           {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using the same javascript as in the example? What are the errors in the console?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yeah i'm using the same code as in the example. And in the example also the onchage is not working

Comment: Have you noticed that instead of `select` and `option`, you get `div`? For me your code works in this example. How exactly does it not work for you?

Comment: I tried using a onchange in the example as well. Still it did not work. If you remove the  'custom-select' class then it works. But then it loses the css.

Comment: Could you provide more info?

Comment: Please tell me what exactly you are failing? You want the same result as in the referenced example, but with your own list, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this task is not entirely clear. You did not report what exactly is not working out for you. I took the code from the source you provided and used your `custom-select-dropdown` class instead of the `custom-select` class. Also, I made edits to the `css`, changing the name of the class that you indicated. And remove the `onchange="agroTimePeriod()"` event from the tag.

And yet, instead of an `option` and `select`, a `div` is generated at the output.

Was it necessary?

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;

x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select-dropdown");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;

  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);

  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {

    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        sl = s.length;
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            yl = y.length;
            for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    });
}
function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {

  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.custom-select-dropdown select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}

.select-items div,.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select-dropdown">
    <select id="agro-time-period" class="custom-input">
       <option disabled selected hidden value="">Ex: Year 2020</option>
       <option value="{{time.code}},{{time.name}}">{{time.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```